# IE6 and IE7 back/forward hash-tag navigation issues

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, navigation, hashtag

I have a website that uses the [jQuery Address plugin from Asual](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) for navigation.

The problem I am having, is that using IE6, and IE7, when the user uses the back/forward buttons the website ends up at an unexpected page.

Here's a cut-down version of what I'm doing right now.

```
$.address.init(function(event) {
    defaultPage = "1";
}).change(function(event) {
    $("#content").html('<div><img src="/images/activity indicator.gif"></div>')
    $("#content").load("./pages/"+names+".html", function(){
    var names = $.map(event.pathNames, function(n) {
        return n.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + n.substr(1);
    }).concat(event.parameters.id ? event.parameters.id.split('.') : []);
        pageScripts[names]();
    });
});
```

If I'm on page `/`, goto `#/1`, goto `#/2`, then goto page `#/3`, I'm on page #/3, no problems with any of that. When I hit "Back" in IE6 or IE7 (Chrome, FF, IE8, IE9 all work fine) when on page `#/3`, I get sent all the way back to page `/`. Clicking forward moves me to page `/#3`.

It skips over the history from hash tabs.

However, the [example from the website](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/api/#) works fine with IE6/IE7. I can't find the functional diferances between what I've done and what it's doing.

Comment: Those aren't hashtags. "hashtag" is Twitter nomenclature.

Comment: @BoltClock You're correct, it's actually called a fragment/anchor identifier in RFC1738. -- However, in javascript the event used to monitor this is called `onhashchange`. So I feel the usage is interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the rel attribute.

`<a href="/deep-link" rel="address:/deep-link">Deep link</a>`

IE6/IE7 seem to respect usage of this for that functionality.

This does have side-effects (ie, every link with REL has an event handler on it now), which may or may not impact your specific implementation.

Note: I'll accept an answer with more care and explanation put into it if you really want to answer this question.